# How do you paragraph dialogue when multiple characters are acting?

Tags: writing, dialogue

So if I'm correct, you start a new paragraph in dialogue every time a new character is the one focused on.

So if character A says something and then does an action that's all one paragraph, but if character A says something and then character B does an action you'd need to separate those things with a paragraph break. But what if character A does something and then both characters are involved in the non-dialogue text?

This is the sample at hand in case anyone's confused:
*"Time sure flies when you're having fun…" David frowned and for a moment Morgan detected something strange in his expression. "You should be nicer when you talk about your father, he's a good man: he looks after you and it's pretty clear he loves you very much."* (both pieces of dialogue are being said by the character David)

Comment: Are you talking about in prose or in a script format?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [Writers.SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/search?q=writing+%5Bdialogue%5D) ?

Comment: @Gandalf Ah probably, I was just googling trying to find the answer and came upon this site, I didn't know it was split into sections

Comment: No problem, my friend. The site has many sections, and I have found it extremely useful for researching topics before committing myself to..umhn....paper. Good luck on your writing.

Answer (score 1):

Either in a paragraph between two spoken lines, or else parenthetically within the lines of one character. At least, that's how I've seen it done.

[image]
<sup>Screen shot from *The Devil's Disciple* by George Bernard Shaw</sup>